# Get notified when a MIDI destination or source changed

Tags: ios, swift, midi, audiokit

Is there any way to get notified when a new MIDI destination/source found or an existing one disconnected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps **receivedMIDISetupChange()** would fit the bill for you?

In a class that conforms to **AKMIDIListener**, try:

```
func receivedMIDISetupChange() {
   print("MIDI Setup Change, midi.inputNames: \(midi.inputNames)")
}
```